# Max score not getting correct results

Tags: excel, vba, max

[image]

```
Sub GetMaxl()

Dim nMonths As Integer, nRegions As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim regionMax As Double, monthMax As Double
Dim maxScore As Integer

With wsSales.Range("A3")
nMonths = Range(.Offset(0, 1), .Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)) _
     .Columns.Count
nRegions = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)) _
     .Rows.Count
     
.Offset(0, nMonths + 1) = "MaxScore"
.Offset(nRegions + 1, 0) = "MaxScore"

For iRow = 1 To nRegions
    regionMax = 0
For iCol = 1 To nMonths
  regionMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(.Offset(iRow, iCol), .End(xlToRight)))
                Debug.Print , regionMax
            Next iCol
            .Offset(iRow, nMonths + 1) = regionMax
        Next iRow
        
        For iCol = 1 To nMonths
            monthMax = 0
            For iRow = 1 To nRegions
                monthMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(.Offset(iRow, iCol), .End(xlDown)))
            Next iRow
        
            .Offset(nRegions + 1, iCol) = monthMax
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the max score against columns and rows in a loop but I am not getting correct results.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easier and faster

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetMaxl()
    Dim Rng As Range, rng_total_right As Range, rng_total_down As Range
    
    Set Rng = wsSales.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    
    'get the ranges for max column and row at right and down
    Set rng_total_right = Intersect(Rng.Offset(, 1), wsSales.Columns(Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count))
    Set rng_total_down = Intersect(Rng.Offset(1, 0), wsSales.Rows(Rng.Row + Rng.Rows.Count))
    
    With rng_total_right ' max column
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-" & Rng.Columns.Count - 1 & "]:RC[-1])" ' insert formulas and calculate them
        .Value = .Value 'replace formulas by values
        .Cells(1) = "MaxScore" 'make header
    End With
    
    With rng_total_down 'max row
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[-" & Rng.Rows.Count - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
        .Value = .Value
        .Cells(1) = "MaxScore"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hello, thankyou for helping although, my column max is coming out to be in the date format, can you tell me what the issue is here? @Алексей Р

Comment: This is most likely due to the column headers that look like dates. You can explicitly set the cell format `.NumberFormat = "0"` - added to the solution.